# can we have two matched clauses in merge

Tags: oracle

Write a single query that Delete the records whose grades are more than 150. Update grades and add 25 to each as internals if records exist. Insert the records if record does not exists with grade as 25.

```
    Merge into employeegrades  empg
    using (select id, name from temp_emp)  e
    on (empg.id= e.id)
    when matched then 
    update set empg.grades = empg.grades + 25
    delete where empg.grades > 150
    when not matched then insert (id,grades) values (e.id, 25);
```

This is working fine but when I modify the statement as below, it is not working:

```
merge into employeegrades eg
using (select id, name from temp_emp)  emp
on (eg.id = emp.id)
when matched and eg.grades > 150 then
delete 
when matched
update set eg.grades = eg.grades+25
when not matched then
insert (id,grades)
values (emp.id, 25);
```

what is wrong with the above query? Can't we specify two matched conditions in merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Can't we specify two matched conditions in merge?"

The [syntax rules in the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) specify two clauses:

- the *merge_update_clause* which executes updates and/or deletes against existing rows
- the *merge_insert_clause* which executes inserts of new rows

That is, the clauses are defined in terms of the actions they implement, not whether they are MATCHED or NOT MATCHED. Because it wouldn't make sense to insert when MATCHED or update when NOT MATCHED.

So, the WHEN MATCHED THEN keyword phrase can only appear once in a MERGE statement because the syntax allows only one *merge_update_clause*.